# merge 2 partitioned folders in a single table

Tags: amazon-redshift, presto, amazon-athena

I am using parquet file format to export data from 2 redshift tables.

```
unload ('select * from some_table')
to 's3://132cols/some_table/'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxx'
PARQUET
PARTITION BY (senderid) include;


unload ('select * from another_table')
to 's3://132cols/another_table/'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxx'
PARQUET
PARTITION BY (senderid) include;
```

The data is partitioned by senderid and therefore I can see 2 folder like...

```
s3://132cols/some_table/senderid=abcd/
s3://132cols/another_table/senderid=abcd/
```

Both the tables has the same structure and same ID's are present in both.
Is there any way to merge these 2 folder to query the data related to sender "abcd" acorss both tables in Athena (or redshift)?

Comment: Try creating a table on top of `s3://132cols/` and run the query. I think it should work. But give a try.

Comment: Use `ALLOWOVERWRITE` and then put the table name as a partition (and perhaps add a random partition, if needed) as written here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62632562/5287221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use partition with your table name.
Can see another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62632562/5287221).

```
unload ($$ select *, 'some_table' as tbl from some_table $$)
to 's3://132cols/'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxx'
PARQUET
PARTITION BY (senderid,tbl) include
ALLOWOVERWRITE;


unload ($$ select *, 'another_table' as tbl from another_table $$)
to 's3://132cols/'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxx'
PARQUET
PARTITION BY (senderid,tbl) include
ALLOWOVERWRITE;
```

Then you will get:

```
s3://132cols/senderid=abcd/tbl=some_table/
s3://132cols/senderid=abcd/tbl=another_table/
```

And now you can create one table on top of `s3://132cols/` with 2 partitions.

Comment: In case of parquet exported data getting this error... HIVE_INVALID_METADATA: Hive metadata for table xx is invalid: Table descriptor contains duplicate columns

Comment: This was because I used "include" parameter along with ALLOWOVERWRITE. This added the "tbl" column to the data and hence the error. Please ignore the above comment.